# Errors after Magento migration

Tags: magento-1.7, migration

I have migrated all of my Magento files and database to the new server. I have changed the database information in `local.xml` file, and changed URLs in the core config table in database.

I get many errors on site, and there is lot of content missing. When I re-uploaded the css, the styles were reloaded and I got the part of the look back.

Now when I go to my cart page, I get 404 error.

This could be related to my server configuration, as for some other sites migration some of my sub-folders are returning me an error, like the `.htaccess` file isn't configured.

The link is www.nuby.hr

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Migration should be a pretty straightforward procedure with a standard Magento install, have you checked the obvious such as proper permissions and ownership of files on the new server?

Answer (score 2):

#### Just repeat your migration - it has clearly gone wrong

```
cd /domains/example.com/http
wget sys.sonassi.com/mage-dbdump.sh
bash mage-dbdump.sh
tar cvfz ../http.tgz . --exclude=var/log --exclude=var/session --exclude=var/cache --exclude=var/*port
```

Then transfer that file to the new server, extract it

```
tar xvfz http.tgz
```

Edit the `./app/etc/local.xml` to reflect the new DB details

Then restore the DB

```
bash mage-dbdump.sh --restore
```

There's good documented procedure that's a little more verbose than the above [here](http://help.sonassihosting.com/general/magento-store-migration-proceedure/).

#### Or automate the process

We've also got an automated script to do quick migrations (without media etc.)

```
wget sys.sonassi.com/mage-bundle.sh
bash mage-bundle.sh
```

This will dump the DB and tar up the document root (excluding tmp files, reports, errors, media, archvies, static content etc.) - for a quick migration.

This is really aimed towards doing dev/test migrations (or backups); but you can use this to get a base of the site over; then supplement the missing files with an `rsync` from the other machine, eg.

```
/usr/bin/rsync -par /domains/example.com/http/ exampleuser@111.111.111.111:/domains/example.com/http/ --delete --exclude=var/log --exclude=var/session --exclude=var/cache --exclude=var/report --exclude=app/etc/local.xml
```

#### Clean up your permissions

And always, check and clean up your permissions, replace `www-data` with your respective user/group

```
chown -R www-data:www-data/home/sonassi/public_html
find /home/sonassi/public_html -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
find /home/sonassi/public_html -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

Or again, read [this](http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/stop-magento-permissions-errors-permanently/) for a more permanent, sophisticated solution.

Comment: Great script, thanks. We've been using a custom pre-commit hook to handle db dumps in the past which works as expected but did not come with the table list optimizations used in your script.

Answer (score 0):

As I had such problems, playing with .htaccess helped.

Especially helped changing `#RewriteBase /magento/`  to `RewriteBase /`    in mentioned `.htaccess`

Keep on mind that that there are several files on the installation.

Hope that helps ;)

Comment: The original problem was the files, when I recopied it, it started to work. 

However, I see now that the redirects are not working.. 

I have manually created links in header and footer.phtml to my inner pages like domainname.com/index.php/aboutus,

And everytime I click on that menu items, I get redirected to the homepage. Weird..